# How to remove this optional word from my app?

Tags: mac, xcode

How to remove this optional word from my app?

[image]

Comment: Youi already asked this question and it got migrated to [so] where it belongs, and answered as well. [in swift 2 how to remove optional word?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33668968)

Comment: it still gives me error in app that's why  i am asking. thank you

Comment: You were told before programming questions belong on [so]

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), where it is already asked and answered: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668968/in-swift-2-how-to-remove-optional-word
Here's a preview of the answer:

> You have to unwrap it.
>
> ```
> if let text = catAge.text {
>     print(text)
> }
> ```